# Is it possible to encrypt with Maas?

Tags: maas

Can Mass install servers on luks encrypted lvm? Using mandos to boot encrypted volume

Many thanks 
David

Answer (score 1):

MAAS does not currently support encrypted LVM. I'd suggest you file a bug request for tracking purposes.